# Database information -> object: how should it be done?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

My application will upon request retrieve information from a database and produce an object from that information. I'm currently considering two different techniques (but I'm open to others as well!) to complete this task:

Method one:

```
class Book {

    private int id;
    private String author;
    private String title;

    public Book(int id) {

        ResultSet book = getBookFromDatabaseById(id);

        this.id = book.id;
        this.author = book.author;
        // ...

    }

}
```

Method two:

```
public class Book {

    private HashMap<String, Object> propertyContainer;

    public Book(int id) {

        this.propertyContainer = getBookFromDatabaseById(id);

    }

    public Object getProperty(String propertyKey) {

        return this.propertyContainer.get(propertyKey);

    }

}
```

With method one, I believe that it's easier to control, limit and possibly access properties, adding new properties, however, becomes smoother with method two.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Please note that this is a stripped down example without error handling and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this problem has been solved in many ways: ORM, DAO, row and table mapper, lots of others.  There's no need to redo it again.

One issue you have to think hard about is coupling and cyclic dependencies between packages.  You might think you're doing something clever by telling a model object how to persist itself, but one consequence of this design choice is coupling between model objects and the persistence tier.  You can't use model objects without persistence if you do this.  They really become one big, unwieldy package.  There's no layering.

Another choice is to have model objects remain oblivious to whether or not they're persisted.  It's a one way dependence that way: persistence knows about model objects, but not the other way around.

Google for those other solutions.  There's no need to beat that dead horse again.

Answer (score 1):

The first method will provide you with type safety for associated accessors so you will know what type of object you are getting back and don.t have to cast to that type the you are expecting (this becomes more important when providing anything other than primitives).

For that reason (plus that it will make the resulting code simpler and easier to read) I would pick the first one. In any large applications you will also be able to quickly, easily and neatly get parameter values back in the code for debug etc. within the object itself.

If anyone else is going to be working on this code also (or your planning on working it after you forget about it) the first one will also help as you know the parameters etc. The second one will only give you this with extensive javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the classical way. The second one is really tricky for nothing.